# Can enter text in input text fields?

Tags: html, text, input, types

Having a slight issue with the input[type="text"] fields. I cannot enter any text into the text fields neither can I highlight the text field with the cursor, the cursor does not even appear or flash at all. Its as if the input field is disabled.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="placeholder text here" />
```

Help will be great. Thanks in Advance

Comment: there is no other element overlapping the input field?

Comment: your html input element looks fine, issue is else where

Comment: Create a fiddle for that, it will solve your issue and give it to us so that we can solve your problem.

Comment: I have checked my html and even validated it @ http://validator.w3.org/ and it shows that the doc has passed. No errors. with 1 warning. which is... Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker.The validator checked your document with an experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker. This feature has been made available for your convenience, but be aware that it may be unreliable, or not perfectly up to date with the latest development of some cutting-edge technologies. If you find any issues with this feature, please report them. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

instead of placeholder make it as value

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="placeholder text" />
```

Comment: eum... no, placeholder works fine. if you set is as value, it will post you placeholde text

Comment: @GertB. is there any attribute for input tag named as placeholder?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp only IE will not show it in early versions

Comment: @GertB. k.. i was not familiar with that attribute

Comment: Why put placeholder as the value for the value attribute. I'm using the placeholder attribute for neatness and better presentation.